# How to generate part of the value for entity field from sequence in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sequence

I have an entity Product which looks something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
@Id
UUID id;

String productCode;
}
```

I want `productCode` to be generated from a sequence called `Product_code_sequence` which is already in my database. When creating new Product, I want to get the next value from the sequence, and then concatenate it with a `String` to get something like "PR000004". 
Also I want the solution to be database independent, meaning I want it to work with Postgres, H2 and any other database that supports sequences.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you `save` your entity and remains on the same transaction, you can set your property like (using `StringUtils` from `commons.lang3`):

```
product.setProductNumber(StringUtils.rightPad(String.valueOf(product.getId()), 5, '0'));
```

right after you just update it:

```
repo.save(product);
```

Comment: The problem is that your solution uses product.getId(), but ID in this situation is UUID, not the value from the sequence that I am interested in.
The sequence used to generate productCode has nothing to do with id.